# How can I convert this tricky complex number into a real number: $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^α}{x^3+1}dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

The problem statement is:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^α}{x^3+1}dx$$
for α in the range −1<α<2.

$$\huge \frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{\frac{i2\pi (\alpha+1)}{3}}} \frac {e^{\frac{i \pi \alpha}{3}}} { 3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}}$$

$\alpha$ is some constant between -1 and 2.

Thanks,

Comment: That is $-\dfrac{\frac\pi3}{\sin\left(\frac\pi3a\right)}e^{-\frac{2\pi i}3} =\dfrac{\frac\pi3}{\sin\left(\frac\pi3a\right)}e^{\frac{\pi i}3} =\dfrac{\frac\pi3}{\sin\left(\frac\pi3a\right)} \left(\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i\right)$, which is not real.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ a real constant or can it be complex?

Comment: This does not seem to be [tag:integration] or [tag:residue-calculus].

Comment: I finally found it.  f-bomb.  Thanks @robjohn.  It is residue-calculus.  A good all-nighter's worth of work and probably not wise to spin my wheels that long on a problem before asking a question on MSE.  Thanks so much :-)

Comment: Meaning I spent all night believing that it must be real, and my computations must be correct, since Wolfram Alpha didn't give an answer, when I went to check with it and instead it gives "standard computation time exceeded", and since you confirmed that it is not a real number, I looked back at my work and found the issue.  Hard lesson learned.  Thanks @RobJohn.

Comment: Maybe the problem that led up to this computation was a residue-calculus problem, but if you don't include more context, this question does not, by itself, involve residue-calculus.

Comment: Yes, understood - sorry...

Comment: Hi @robjohn, I just edited my question to update the number.  Is this now real?  I added 1 to $\alpha$ ... thanks,

Comment: And if it is real, can you offer a hint on how to best show it?  Thanks @robjohn

Comment: Now it looks like $\dfrac{\frac\pi3}{\sin\left(\frac\pi3(a+1)\right)}$

Comment: Awesome! It's real!! I just posted the integral too.  How do you think I can approach showing the number is real?  Just expand out all the Euler formulas, or is there a more clever way? Thanks @robjohn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiply by $\frac{e^{\frac{-i\pi(a+1)}3}}{e^{\frac{-i\pi(a+1)}3}}$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{\frac{i2\pi(a+1)}3}}\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi a}3}} {3e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}}
&=\frac{2\pi i}{e^{-\frac{i\pi(a+1)}3}-e^{\frac{i\pi(a+1)}3}}\frac{e^{-\frac{i\pi}3}} {3e^{\frac{2\pi i}3}}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\frac\pi3}{-\sin\left(\frac\pi3(a+1)\right)}e^{-i\pi}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{\frac\pi3}{\sin\left(\frac\pi3(a+1)\right)}
\end{align}
$$
since $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

Comment: This has come up so often in past problems (finalizing the answer to include a sine, cosine, sinh, or cosh), yet still so hard to see.  Thanks so much for the cool technique, @RobJohn.  Have a great night! :-)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216), which generalizes your integral.

Comment: Ok awesome -- thanks so much for the link.  I'll be sure to read it in more detail after some sleep. Thanks and good night @robjohn!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Assuming $x\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\frac{2\pi i}{1-e^{\frac{i2\pi x}{3}}} \frac {e^{\frac{i \pi x}{3}}} { 3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}}=$$
$$\frac{\left(2\pi i\right)\cdot\left(e^{\frac{x\pi i}{3}}\right)}{\left(1-e^{\frac{i2\pi x}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{2\pi i e^{\frac{x\pi i}{3}}}{\left(1-e^{\frac{i2\pi x}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{2\pi i e^{\frac{x\pi i}{3}}}{\left(1-e^{\frac{i2\pi x}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{2\pi i\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)i\right)}{\left(1-e^{\frac{i2\pi x}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{-2\pi\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)+2i\pi\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)}{\left(1-e^{\frac{i2\pi x}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(3e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)}=$$
$$\frac{-2\pi\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)+2i\pi\cos\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)}{3(i+\sqrt{3})e^{\frac{i\pi x}{3}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{3}\right)}$$